# Binding a Minecraft command to a key

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way to bind a Minecraft command to a hotkey?

For example, I’d like a way to toggle between modes (survivla/creative) by pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> so that if I’m in a nasty pinch (like getting poisoned by a spider and being unable to fight back because the game suddenly lags really badly) and want to avoid losing a full inventory of valuables that I worked hard to get over the past five hours, I can quickly switch to creative mode.

I searched for a mod to do this and (surprisingly) came up empty; all I could find was the [macro/keybind](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/467504-164-macro-keybind-mod-0911/) mod which requires LiteLoader and doesn’t seem to be able to bind arbitrary commands to keys.

The closest thing to a solution that I could find were suggestions to automate it with AutoHotkey, but that is no good because some keystrokes to get lost (probably due to the game’s CPU load), so pressing the hotkey will result in `amemode 1` or `/amemo 0` and such.

Is there a way to bind a command to a key so that it always works correctly?

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question - there's no way to do this natively.

Comment: `You seem to have answered your own question` @dlras2, wow, so you’re saying that my “google-fu” and research skills are perfect and flawless? Good to know.

Comment: I believe the mod Single Player Commands allows binding arbitrary console commands to keys? Haven't used it, but I recall an old Nerd³ video demonstrating his custom keybinds, and I'm pretty sure he was using SPC. Maybe someone who has done it can answer from experience.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, yes I think I’ve seen that, unfortunately it has yet to be updated. I even tried using the latest version (for 1.6.2) anyway (on 1.6.4), but unlike some mods that work without having to be updated, this one doesn’t. Regardless, that’s a valid answer even if it doesn’t quite work (until it is updated), so if you want to write it as an answer, I’ll accept it for now.

Comment: I would have to research it from scratch, since I know it takes some finicky config work but I don't already know the details. I'll let someone else have that rep. :)

Comment: Can't you record a macro that goes through the motion for you?  [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) is a program you can use to do it.

Comment: @Batophobia, like I said, I already created an AutoHotkey macro, but only works sometimes, often the game only receives *some* of the keys which causes invalid commands. I’m looking for something that is built-in (natively, a mod, whatever) so that it always performs the command without having to “manually” type. That is, something that can directly call the function that the command performs rather than going through the keys (regardless of the source of the keys).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie, I checked SPC again last night; in fact, the file `SinglePlayerCommands-MC1.6.2_V4.9` has a timestamp of Nov.5-1:13am. It didn’t work, which is why I gave up and started typing this question before going to bed. It seems that someone posted an updated version that is compatible with 1.6.4 just two hours later. Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: [Someone doesn’t like](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dRYjt.png) the idea of binding commands to hotkeys (or maybe they just didn’t like my example scenario and believe that everybody should play the game they way they do… and couldn’t conceive of any other usage). ◔_◔

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that [*Single Player Commands*](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-162-single-player-commands-v49-official-download-spc-noclip/page__st__29540#entry25696929) has finally been updated to 1.6.4 (of course MC 1.7.2 is out now…)

With this, you can bind commands to keys as so:

```
/bind y gamemode 1
```

You can also use `/bindid` to set a special key via its [key-code](http://www.planetminecraft.com/blog/minecraftsingleplayercommands-195-download-tutorial/). It can’t quite do something like toggling (which would require knowing or keeping track of the current state), but it does let you bind a key to a macro (with the `/macro` command), so it might be possible to cobble together something that can toggle, but even if not, it’s still a perfectly suitable solution for most applications. (In the case of switching modes, <kbd>Tab</kbd> can be bound to creative mode to quickly avoid dying and then switching back to survival can be done with another key or manual.)

Comment: Nice! Aside, it may be possible (as was often done in the days of Quake) to bind a macro that runs the desired command then rebinds its own key to *another* macro that is the other half of the toggle (which then does the same rebinding trick to complete the toggle), in order to get a functional toggle key.