# Can I bind a command to a key in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, is there a way to bind a key to teleport to a specific player or place instead of typing a command?

Comment: Looks like this has already been [asked here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/138866/binding-a-minecraft-command-to-a-key)

Answer (score 1):

No, you're limited to all buttons that actually do stuff already. There is no way to bind more keys, other than the existing ones.
If you're talking only about vanilla with no command blocks, you could do macros with additional software, that would type/tab in the command you need.
If you want to use command blocks, you could bind certain dropped items to make something happen.

Comment: Are you sure of this? The link I posted in the comment on the question seems to say otherwise.